# Q&A Template for "What are risks related with X and how to defend against them?"

Tags: discussion, acceptable-question, asking-questions, acceptable-answer, answers

Is it a good idea to try to use (as standard "de-facto", not forcing it on security.SE users) Q&A template ?

My current case it I'd like to make some specific quesion, like:

```
Q:
"How X can be broken? Is there a way to defend such attack?"
```

And recive answers in form :

```
A:
Broken: might be broken with this and that... 
Defend: defend
against this with that and that approach...
```

What do you think about approach?
If you think, it's ok, Could you propose the best way/template how to ask such kind of questions, to make it clear to people how to form answers?

Answer (score 3):

It's a nice idea. However given the independent distributed nature of the questions and answers on IT Security and Stack Exchange sites in general, it seems unlikely that the format will take hold.

Personally I would like to see questions explicitly state:

- assets needing protection
- threat environment
- infrastructure

As it is questions often don't even clearly state the main concern. It seems the best way to achieve a more consistent format is to edit questions and answers.

So, welcome to the volunteer editor corps!

Comment: Agreed, and any description of risk appetite or what industry they are in helps us tailor answers as well. I would second @this.josh's welcome - editing to improve questions and answers is a very useful service!